# How to save a photo location or actual photo as a class variable?

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I have a class with a variable named Photo. The user is using the PhotoChooserTask to select the photo, and it is being displayed in an Image control. This part of the application, the chooser and display, works fine.

I would like to save either the location/path of the chosen photo or the actual photo so that it will be available for display into an Image control when the user ran the application later.
The whole class is saved using serialization, and I don't know how to save/serialize the photo (or the photo path) that way.

The photo should be still available to the user through the Camera Roll as well.

Any help, link or code, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a [PhotoChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) you will will get a [PhotoResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.photoresult%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) instance from the [PhotoChooserTask.Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ff707989%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event.

You can then [PhotoResult.ChosenPhoto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.photoresult.chosenphoto%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) stream and save the content to a byte array (easy serialization) or a file in Isolated Storage.

Comment: Is there a way just to save the location of the Photo? Without coping it to byte array or isolated storage?
Thx Eitan